# Error: [ThemeProvider] Please make your theme prop a plain object

Tags: reactjs, emotion

Hello I'm trying to use the theme of emotion, but I came across this error and I'm not able to solve

code:

```
const [theme, setTheme] = usePersistedState('theme', light);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme.title === 'light' ? dark : light);
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>a</button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

my hook:

```
function usePersistedState(key, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const storageValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (storageValue) {
      return JSON.parse(storageValue);
    } else {
      return initialState;
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state.type));
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

my themes:

dark:

```
export default {
  type: 'dark',

  colors: {
    primary: '#222',
    secondary: '#DF2935',

    background: '#333',
    text: '#fff',
  },
};
```

light:

```
export default {
  type: 'light',

  colors: {
    primary: '#3772FF',
    secondary: '#DF2935',

    background: '#f5f5f5',
    text: '#333',
  },
};
```

I don't know how to solve this problem I basically save my theme in my local storage to be able to save my preferences

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: [ThemeProvider] Please make your theme prop a plain object

Comment: I'd say first make sure you importing the theme correctly, is it an actual object?

Comment: yes i imported the theme correctly i posted them in question

Comment: It would help if you could put a small reproducible sample code in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: ok i go put now

Comment: I tested it on the code and it was normal
but on my localhost it doesn't work wtf

now i have this problem:
A cross-origin error was thrown.

Comment: hey, i am getting this error "ThemeProvider: Please make your "theme" prop an object."
can you help me with this?